# Flutter 'This document does not exist. It will not appear in queries or snapshots'

Tags: flutter

[image: Firebase Console]
[image: Flutter code]

use the document ID from the user authentication on firebase create a document inside the main collection but it shows that:
that does exist.
Can I access the subcollection in a firebase document which shows 'This document does not exist. It will not appear in queries or snapshots'. If so, how the document will be created correctly in the firebase.